# In nextjs13, such as how to use Dynamic-routes correctly

Tags: next.js

In the project I want /profile and /profile/[id] to map to one page. While nextjs provides profile/[... id]/page.tsx。 This but, but I don't want too many parameters, and now I'm not sure how to implement such a route

profile/[... id]/page.tsx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To achieve the routing behavior where both /profile and /profile/[id] map to the same page, you can use a catch-all route with a custom route parameter in Next.js. Here's how you can do it:

Crete Your Page:

```js
const Profile = ({ params }) => {
  const { id } = params
  return (
    <div>
      <h1>Profile Page</h1>
      <p>User ID: {id || 'No ID specified'}</p>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Profile;
```

Define the Custom Route Parameter:

Next, you can define a custom route parameter in your next.config.js file. This parameter will allow both /profile and /profile/[id] to be handled by the same page.

```js
// next.config.js
module.exports = {
  async rewrites() {
    return [
      {
        source: '/profile',
        destination: '/profile/[...id]',
      },
    ];
  },
};
```

Answer (score 0):

On the documentation there is [Optional catch-all segments](https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/routing/dynamic-routes#optional-catch-all-segments) to make `/profile` and `/profile/id` render the same route use `app/profile/[[...id]]/page.tsx`

This will catch `/profile`, `/profile/whatever-the-id-is`, and `/profile/nesting/ids`

To type this in typescript:

```js
type Props {
  params: {
    id?: string[]
  }
}
```

| Route | Example URL | params |
| --- | --- | --- |
| `app/profile/[[...id]]/page.tsx` | `/profile` | `{}` |
| `app/profile/[[...id]]/page.tsx` | `/profile/a` | `{ id: ['a'] }` |
| `app/profile/[[...id]]/page.tsx` | `/profile/a/b` | `{ id: ['a', 'b']` } |
| `app/profile/[[...id]]/page.tsx` | `/profile/a/b/c` | `{ id: ['a', 'b', 'c']` } |

[©](https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/routing/dynamic-routes#optional-catch-all-segments)

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but I'm sure yes only needs one parameter